# Incessant prompting for id_rsa passphrase

Tags: macos, mac, ssh, git, public-key

Running on Mac OS X and I switched to zsh a couple months ago & started using git quite heavily.  At each initial login now I'm getting a prompt for my .ssh/id_rsa passphrase:

```
starting...
Enter passphrase for ~/.ssh/id_rsa
Identity added: ~/.ssh/id_dsa (path to id_dsa)
```

I assume I could just regenerate my rsa cert, however I was curious as to what the "best" approach would be in this case so as to not have to enter a passphrase each time now.

Comment: Looks like a `ssh-add` in your zsh "profile" file?

Comment: Interesting, it appears that with oh-my-zsh there is a "ssh-agent.plugin.zsh".  I was not aware of it running each and every time the shell starts, but apparently it is.  Interestingly it only fires this ssh-add after system restarts.  A real hassle when you start it with a few windows and you have to go through each one.  What would be your suggestion in this regard; am I gaining an advantage by leaving this active?

Comment: I believe OS X already runs ssh-agent automatically – supposedly even integrated with Keychain – so there would be no advantage in using the zsh plugin.